# Prove for all all $x\in\mathbb{R}: \exp(x-1) \geq x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, exponential-function

i just tried to solve this question, which is a small part of a bigger one.

Prove for all all $x \in \mathbb{R}: \exp(x-1) \geq x$

My first attempt was to simplify:

$$ e^{x-1} \geq x $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow \ln(e^{x-1}) \geq \ln(x) $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow x-1 \geq \ln(x) $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow x \geq \ln(x)+1 $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow e^x \geq e^{\ln(x)}+e^1 $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow e^x \geq x+e $$

My idea is that $e$ power $x$ is of course greater equal $x+e$. Is this correct  and if yes is it enough?

Comment: Careful: when you try to run this backwards you have $\ln x$ which only makes sense for positive $x$s, and you may want this for all $x$s.

Comment: ok yes. you got a point :-/ you have an idea how to solve?

Comment: You made a mistake at the point where you asserted the "equivalent" inequality $e^x\le e^{\ln x}+e^1$.  That inequality is not true.  For example, if $x=1$, then $e^{\ln 1}=e^0=1$ so we have $e^1\lt1+e^1$, not $\ge$.

Comment: Also notice that $e^{\ln(x)+1}=e^{\ln x}\cdot e=x\cdot e\neq x+e$.

Comment: To further emphasize the two previous comments, note that $e^x\geq x+e$ implies $1\geq e$ which is pretty unlikely.

Comment: ok this was a huge mistake i do understand now :) - i have really some maths issues

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630481/prove-expx-geq-1x-forall-x-in-mathbbr (and probably some more).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{x-1}-x.$

Thus, $f'(x)=e^{x-1}-1$, which says that $x_{\min}=1$.

Id est, $$f(x)\geq f(1)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: ok this was fast ^^ So my idea was totally wrong :-( but thank you :-)

Comment: @hukachaka You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

the answer Michael gave is a good answer but if you want different way,
$$e^{x-1}=x\implies x=1$$ now because both $x$ and $e^{x-1}$ are continuous you just need to check one value of $x$ that is above $1$ and one that is less. for example:$$\text{for $x<1,\,x=0$},\,e^{0-1}={1\over e}\gt0\\\text{for $x>1,\,x=2$},\,e^{2-1}=e\gt2$$
therefore $$e^{x-1}\ge1$$

Comment: thank you very much. I think i will try to understang both answers first :-)

Comment: @hukachaka sure, if there is anything you want further explanation just ask

Comment: thank you very much :)))

Comment: Why does $e^{x-1}=x$ imply $x=1$?

Comment: @MartinR $e^{x-1}=x\implies x-1=\ln x\implies x=1$

Comment: Why does the last implication hold?

Comment: So you have $e^{x-1}=x \Longrightarrow x-1 = \ln x \Longrightarrow e^x = ex$. Where to you *prove* that this implies $x=1$?